# Is 00 a valid month for a credit card?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

When I call `Stripe.card.validateExpiry("00","2014")` it returns true, when using stripe.js.

```
Stripe.card.validateExpiry(00,2014)
```

returns false.

I am just going to pass in ints, BUT, the documentation says you can pass in strings as well. What's the deal here?

```
Stripe.card.validateExpiry('02', '15')      // false -- * WHY is this false? Feb 2015.
Stripe.card.validateExpiry('02', '10')      // false -- makes sense
Stripe.card.validateExpiry('02', '2020')    // true -- makes sense
Stripe.card.validateExpiry(2, 2020)         // true -- makes sense
```

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js

Comment: So you're asking a question to a Stripe developer about why they have implemented it that way or what?

Comment: I'd imagine it's ('02', '15') is false because it's taking it to mean the year 15, not 2015. That's why the two true statements are '2020' and not '20'. 00 should not be a valid month, though.

Comment: @zerkms, I am asking why "00" is considered a valid month, when 00 isn't

Comment: @Josh: assuming the CC haven't been used in year 15 A.D. it makes no sense to assume 15 is something else but 2015

Comment: @The Internet: that's how the library developer developer it. I'm sure the original developer is the only person who can tell you why they do that in that way.

Comment: @Josh, oh I see, you need all 4 digits. What about ("00","2014")?

Comment: What makes it worse - is this line `exp_year: two or four digit number representing the card's expiration year, e.g. 2013.`

Comment: In all fairness - it's a confusing series of documentation, and could be better expained - because when it comes to validating payments - I'd rather know exactly what's going on, and not guess.

Comment: So should I always stay away from using strings when validating expiration dates?

Comment: Which stripe.js are you using? I'm testing now, and `Stripe.card.validateExpiry(00, 2014)` is returing true for me...

Comment: @Xymostech, try Stripe.card.validateExpiry("00", "2014")

Comment: Both of them return true. Here: [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Hgam/1/) This is using https://js.stripe.com/v2/

Comment: @Xymostech, Ok then, Why is "00" a valid month?

Comment: I don't know. You'll have to ask the stripe developers. But your question seems to be more about the library inconsistency then the weird '0' month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a couple of different permutations. It seems to work fine for me, with one exception: The year requires all 4 digits (i.e. `14` is not recognized as `2014`).

*All the following tests were done with js.stripe.com/v2*

**Testing Integer variables**

```
console.log("(00, 2014) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(00, 2014));    // returns false
console.log("(01, 2014) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(01, 2014));    // true
console.log("(02, 2014) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(02, 2014));    // true
console.log("(03, 2014) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(03, 2014));    // true
console.log("(04, 2014) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(04, 2014));    // true
console.log("(05, 2014) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(05, 2014));    // true
console.log("(06, 2014) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(06, 2014));    // true
console.log("(07, 2014) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(07, 2014));    // true
console.log("(08, 2014) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(08, 2014));    // true
console.log("(09, 2014) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(09, 2014));    // true
console.log("(10, 2014) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(10, 2014));    // true
console.log("(11, 2014) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(11, 2014));    // true
console.log("(12, 2014) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(12, 2014));    // true
console.log("(13, 2014) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(13, 2014));    // returns false
```

**Testing String variables**

```
console.log("('00', '2014') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('00', '2014')); // returns false
console.log("('01', '2014') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('01', '2014')); // true
console.log("('02', '2014') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('02', '2014')); // true
console.log("('03', '2014') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('03', '2014')); // true
console.log("('04', '2014') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('04', '2014')); // true
console.log("('05', '2014') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('05', '2014')); // true
console.log("('06', '2014') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('06', '2014')); // true
console.log("('07', '2014') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('07', '2014')); // true
console.log("('08', '2014') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('08', '2014')); // true
console.log("('09', '2014') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('09', '2014')); // true
console.log("('10', '2014') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('10', '2014')); // true
console.log("('11', '2014') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('11', '2014')); // true
console.log("('12', '2014') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('12', '2014')); // true
console.log("('13', '2014') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('13', '2014')); // returns false
```

**Testings Integers with 2 digit years**

```
console.log("(00, 14) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(00, 14));  // false
console.log("(01, 14) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(01, 14));  // false
console.log("(02, 14) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(02, 14));  // false
console.log("(03, 14) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(03, 14));  // false
console.log("(04, 14) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(04, 14));  // false
console.log("(05, 14) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(05, 14));  // false
console.log("(06, 14) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(06, 14));  // false
console.log("(07, 14) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(07, 14));  // false
console.log("(08, 14) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(08, 14));  // false
console.log("(09, 14) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(09, 14));  // false
console.log("(10, 14) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(10, 14));  // false
console.log("(11, 14) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(11, 14));  // false
console.log("(12, 14) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(12, 14));  // false
console.log("(13, 14) =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry(13, 14));  // false
```

**Testing Strings with 2 digit years**

```
console.log("('00', '14') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('00', '14'));  // false
console.log("('01', '14') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('01', '14'));  // false
console.log("('02', '14') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('02', '14'));  // false
console.log("('03', '14') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('03', '14'));  // false
console.log("('04', '14') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('04', '14'));  // false
console.log("('05', '14') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('05', '14'));  // false
console.log("('06', '14') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('06', '14'));  // false
console.log("('07', '14') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('07', '14'));  // false
console.log("('08', '14') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('08', '14'));  // false
console.log("('09', '14') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('09', '14'));  // false
console.log("('10', '14') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('10', '14'));  // false
console.log("('11', '14') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('11', '14'));  // false
console.log("('12', '14') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('12', '14'));  // false
console.log("('13', '14') =>", Stripe.card.validateExpiry('13', '14'));  // false
```